# How to set disable/reaonly Kendo UI controls

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I have a form with various controls such as numeric boxes, comboboxes and datepickers. Is there a way how to disable/make them readonly all at once? Something like with the jQuery Mobile set the attribute and call the `refresh()` method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use kendo's widgetInstance method.

```
$("[data-role]").each(function (index, el) {
   var widget = kendo.widgetInstance($(el));
   if (widget.enable) {
       widget.enable(false);
   }                
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by the below line of jQuery.

```
$("#yourdivid textarea, #yourdivid input, #yourdivid select").attr('disabled',true);
```

Comment: That's classic approach, if you use basic HTML without Kendo or jQuery Mobile. Since these frameworks completely change the HTML and the original element is usually not visible you need to call some kind of rebuild action.